# Sorting by custom type in ravendb

Tags: ravendb

I have this class

```
class MyType{
    public System.Version Version { get; set; }
}
```

I have a json converter that transforms `Version` to `string` using `Version.Parse` and `Version.ToString()`. So my document is something like:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Now, I want to sort by that field, I don't want the default lexicographical sort, I want to use `System.Version`'s.

I've tried this:

```
    public override IndexDefinition CreateIndexDefinition()
    {
        return new IndexDefinition
        {
            Map = "from q in docs.MyTypes select new { Version = Version.Parse(q.Version) }",
            SortOptions = {
                { "Version", SortOptions.Custom }
            }
        };
    }
```

But I get an exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Lucene.Net.Search.SortField.GetComparator(Int32 numHits, Int32 sortPos)
at Lucene.Net.Search.FieldValueHitQueue.OneComparatorFieldValueHitQueue..ctor(SortField[] fields, Int32 size)
at Lucene.Net.Search.FieldValueHitQueue.Create(SortField[] fields, Int32 size)
at Lucene.Net.Search.TopFieldCollector.Create(Sort sort, Int32 numHits, Boolean fillFields, Boolean trackDocScores, Boolean trackMaxScore, Boolean docsScoredInOrder)
at Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher.Search(Weight weight, Filter filter, Int32 nDocs, Sort sort, Boolean fillFields)
at Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher.Search(Weight weight, Filter filter, Int32 nDocs, Sort sort)
```

Is there another way to do this? or can this code be fixed?

### Edit (Solution)

As [suggested by ayende](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39435880/979293) we ended up with this code:

```
public class SortByVersionIndex<T> : AbstractIndexCreationTask<T>
    where T : IVersionable
{
    public SortByVersionIndex()
    {
        Map = xs => from x in xs
                    let v = Version.Parse(x.Version.ToString())
                    select new
                    {
                        Version = v.Build + v.Minor * 1000 + v.Major * 100000
                    };

        Sort(x => x.Version, SortOptions.Long);
    }

    public override string IndexName => $"{typeof(T).Name}/SortByVersion";
}
```

We needed indexes like this one for several collections, that's why we had to make it generic and override the `IndexName`

The `Version.Parse(x.Version.ToString())` is a way to have the code statically typed in c# and `x.Version` being a string on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to provide a custom sorter in RavenDB.
The Custom option is there because it is a directly copy of the Lucene feature we expose.
What you can do is to create an instance of the version at indexing time, then translate to a long, then compare on that.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question with the solution we ended up with, is there a better way to handle the type mismatch between client and server? I like that our solution is statically typed but the `Version.Parse(x.Version.ToString())` feels odd. Thanks again